# libtermcap.so.2 file not found while doing heroku create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, heroku, fedora

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and want to push app to heroke.While entering the command `heroku create` i get the following error

```
`require': libtermcap.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/yats/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yum install ncurses-devel
```

Just do

```
ln -s  /usr/lib64/libtermcap.so /usr/lib64/libtermcap.so.2
```